# Why an img with srcset requests more than 1 version of the image

Tags: html, css, srcset

I have the following tag and checking the network panel, I see it is not working as I was expecting. I don't know if this is the normal behaviour for local or good-bandwith testing or if there is something wrong with my code:

```
<img sizes="
  (min-width: 300px) 300px,
  (min-width: 450px) 600px,
  (min-width: 1000px) 1200px,
  ((max-width: 450px) and (min-resolution: 2dppx)) 600px"
srcset="
  /uploaded/coso_300.jpg 300w,
  /uploaded/coso_600.jpg 600w,
  /uploaded/coso_1200.jpg 1200w,
  /uploaded/coso_2000.jpg 2000w"
src="/uploaded/coso.jpg" >
```

The files are being selected at a 320px wide viewport in this order:

- `coso_600.jpg` > `coso.jpg`  (I expected `coso_300.jpg`)

at a 600px wide:

- same as before (I expected `coso_300.jpg`)

at a 1300px wide:

- `coso_300.jpg` > `coso.jpg` > `coso_600.jpg`  (I expected `coso_1200.jpg`)

at a 2500px wide screen:

- same (I expected `coso_2000.jpg`)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<picture>` tag. 
Refer [HTML  element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)

```
<picture>
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 300px)"
    srcset="coso_300.jpg">
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 600px)"
    srcset="coso_600.jpg">
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 1200px)"
    srcset="coso_1200.jpg">
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 2000px)"
    srcset="coso_2000.jpg">
  <img 
    src="/uploaded/coso.jpg" 
    alt="Image">
</picture>
```